# How to assign a product to particular user in drupal commerce programmatically?

Tags: commerce

I am using drupal commerce in my site I need to assign a product programatically to user for this I am using this code.

```
$selpro = product id.
$line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new(commerce_product_load($selpro));
commerce_cart_product_add($user->uid, $line_item);
```

But this code is not working for me.

Comment: I have some product that I need to assign some specific users without any charge.

Comment: For some special customer I need this functionality. If you have any answer please let me know.